# pandas isin based on a single row

Tags: pandas

Now I have:

```
ss    dd    list
A     B     [B,E,F]
C     E     [C,H,E]
A     C     [A,D,E]
```

I want to rule out rows that both ss and dd are in list. So we rule out row 2. Function isin() checks if ss and dd are in all rows of list each time, which is not giving me the result.

Please do not use loop cause my dataset is too large.
Output should be:

```
ss    dd    list
A     B     [B,E,F]
A     C     [A,D,E]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we flatten your `list` column to a dataframe and using `isin`(here `index` is do matter , that is why I using original dataframe `index` to create the `cdf`)

```
cdf=pd.DataFrame(df['list'].tolist(),index=df.index)
mask=(cdf.isin(df.ss).any(1))&(cdf.isin(df.dd).any(1))
df[~mask]
Out[589]: 
  ss dd       list
0  A  B  [B, E, F]
2  A  C  [A, D, E]
```